# Partial center in environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, environments, page-breaking

I'm writing a lab manual with step by step directions. Some directions include screenshots. To keep the screenshot with the line of direction, I use samepage. I am exploring an environment I can use for efficiency. The issue is that I want the screenshot centered, but not the line of text prior. Is it possible to write such an environment? Here's my MWE.

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,12pt]{report}
\def\usletterpaper{\usepackage[bottom=1in,hmarginratio=1:1,letterpaper]{geometry}}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newenvironment{myItem}{%
   \item 
   \begin{samepage}
   \begin{center}
   }
   {
   \end{center}
   \end{samepage}
   }

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter Blah} \label{chap:ChpBlah}
Chapter text here.

\begin{enumerate}
\item Step directions here.
\item Step directions here too.
\begin{myItem}Open Chrome or Firefox and browse to url here. 
\includegraphics[scale=0.55]{AnyImage.png}\end{myItem} %only the image should be centered
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No, not this way. You can simplify by using an (optional) argument to the environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the environment `myItem`  effectively starts with the `center` environment, anything written after `\begin{myItem}` deliberately is centered (unless shifted additionally).

I suggest to use an (optional) argument for the description text, this way the description text will be given to `\item #1` first and then the centering occurs.

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,12pt]{report}
\def\usletterpaper{\usepackage[bottom=1in,hmarginratio=1:1,letterpaper]{geometry}}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newenvironment{myItem}[1][]{%
   \item #1
   \begin{samepage}
     \begin{center}
     }
     {%
     \end{center}
   \end{samepage}
 }

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter Blah} \label{chap:ChpBlah}
Chapter text here.

\begin{enumerate}
\item Step directions here.
\item Step directions here too.
\begin{myItem}[Open Chrome or Firefox and browse to url here.]
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{ente}\end{myItem} %only the image should be centered
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Checking if `#1` is used at all:**

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,12pt]{report}
\def\usletterpaper{\usepackage[bottom=1in,hmarginratio=1:1,letterpaper]{geometry}}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newenvironment{myItem}[1][]{%
  \notblank{#1}{
  \item #1
  }{}
   \begin{samepage}
     \begin{center}
     }
     {%
     \end{center}
   \end{samepage}
 }

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter Blah} \label{chap:ChpBlah}
Chapter text here.

\begin{enumerate}
\item Step directions here.
\item Step directions here too.
\begin{myItem}[Open Chrome or Firefox and browse to url here.]
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{ente}\end{myItem} %only the image should be centered
\end{enumerate}

\clearpage
\begin{enumerate}
\item Step directions here.
\item Step directions here too.
\begin{myItem}
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{ente}
\end{myItem}
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

Comment: @PepPaddy: You're welcome. I will add an improvement version later on, that checks for the `1st` argument and omits the `\item` if it is not present.

Answer (score 1):

The following `myItem` environment redefines `\includegraphics` to place the image centred. As such, you can place content *before* or *after* the image and they will be justified as set previously.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newenvironment{myItem}{%
  \item%
    \let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
    \renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{%
      \par\nobreak
      {\centering\oldincludegraphics[##1]{##2}\par}}
  }{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter Blah}
Chapter text here.

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Step directions here.
  \item Step directions here too.
  \begin{myItem}
    Open Chrome or Firefox and browse to URL here.
    \includegraphics[scale=0.55]{example-image}%only the image should be centered
  \end{myItem}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I've minimized the example slightly as it seems like you're not interested in having text after the image. However, if you do, one could find a way around that as well, making content stay on the same page.